# Unknown issue in Nutch elastic indexing

Tags: elasticsearch, nutch

I am very new to Apache Nutch. I tried crawling a small set of urls by running nutch 1.12 in distributed mode on aws emr. Everything works fine until the dedup crawldb phase. During the indexing phase (elastic 2.4.3), I am running into the following error :-

```
17/02/08 22:55:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000003_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:55:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:55:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000006_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:55:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000002_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:55:52 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 7%
17/02/08 22:55:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:55:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000009_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

17/02/08 22:55:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000005_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

17/02/08 22:55:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000007_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

17/02/08 22:55:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000008_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:55:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000004_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:55:52 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000010_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:55:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
17/02/08 22:55:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000011_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
Container killed by the ApplicationMaster.
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143

17/02/08 22:55:53 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000012_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:55:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000013_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:55:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000014_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:00 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000010_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000008_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:01 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000003_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000005_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000007_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000002_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000004_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000009_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:03 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000001_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000011_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000012_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 7%
17/02/08 22:56:05 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000006_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
17/02/08 22:56:06 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000013_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000014_1, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:10 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000003_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000009_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000008_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000007_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000010_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000005_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000004_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000002_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000011_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000006_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000013_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000012_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1486588453285_0032_r_000014_2, Status : FAILED
Error: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
17/02/08 22:56:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
17/02/08 22:56:19 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1486588453285_0032 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1486588453285_0032_r_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:0 failedReduces:1
```

I tried to resolve this by the solution given here -[Unknown issue in Nutch elastic indexer with nutch REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916877/unknown-issue-in-nutch-elastic-indexer-with-nutch-rest-api), but the issue persists even after replacing guava dependency. To replace the guava dependency, I followed steps given on this page - [Use bootstrap to replace default jar on EMR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207658/use-bootstrap-to-replace-default-jar-on-emr)

Comment: How do I see hadoop log on master node?